Problem with CORS configuration in Spring Boot
I read the information I found on this site and others. I thought it would be simple, but the TypeError: Failed to fetch error persists in various scenarios. I am describing the situation and hope someone can point out my mistake.
My project is a Spring Boot application (it’s for educational purposes). The main part of the project is deployed on port 8080. HTML pages are also within this project. The page has two sections: subscription change and personal data change. There are no errors on the frontend when changing personal data, as the requests from the frontend go to controllers on port 8080.
However, when changing a subscription, the request from the frontend is sent to the subscription change controller on port 8080, which in turn calls the payment controller (also on port 8080). The payment controller sends data to a mock banking server running on port 8081. The subscription changes as expected, but the response does not return to the frontend, and instead, the TypeError: Failed to fetch error appears.
I have configured CORS settings on both ports 8080 and 8081 (together and separately), and I have added annotations to controllers on all ports, both together and separately. I have also modified my WebSecurityConfig settings. Despite all these attempts, the issue remains unresolved.
I have reverted all my changes to the initial state (before the error appeared). Currently, the only place where CORS is mentioned in my code is in my WebSecurityConfig. Of course, when attempting to add WebMvcConfigurer in WebSecurityConfig, .cors().disable() was either enabled or absent. I tried different options, but the issue was not resolved.
I hope for your help and explanation, specifically for my case.
After testing the code in various ways, I found that the error is indeed not related to CORS. I think the issue might be in the transition from the displayAllSubscription() function to updateSubscription(subscriptionName) after clicking the Subscribe button. For testing, I called the updateSubscription(subscriptionName) function directly, bypassing displayAllSubscription(), and the code executed without errors. However, when updateSubscription(subscriptionName) is called through displayAllSubscription(), I see through debugging that the function stops executing at the fetch call. After that, the debugger stops. What could be the problem? I have updated the code and attached a screenshot. I added more screenshots. I don’t understand why it’s skipping the response. Could it be that it’s not coming through because of displayAllSubscription()?
function displayAllSubscription() {
const findAllSubmenu = document.getElementById('findAllSubmenu');
if (!findAllSubmenu) {
    console.error('Element with id "findAllSubmenu" not found.');
    return;
}
findAllSubmenu.innerHTML = '<ul>';
subscriptions.forEach(subscription => {
    const subscriptionName = subscription.subscriptionName || 'Unknown';
    const subscriptionPrice = subscription.subscriptionPrice !== null
    && subscription.subscriptionPrice !== undefined ? subscription.subscriptionPrice : 'N/A';
    const subscriptionDurationTime = subscription.subscriptionDurationTime !== null
    && subscription.subscriptionDurationTime !== undefined ? subscription.subscriptionDurationTime : 'N/A';
    findAllSubmenu.innerHTML += `
        <li class="submenu-all-subscriptions-item">
            <p class="submenu-all-subscriptions-name">Name: ${subscriptionName}</p>
            <p class="submenu-all-subscriptions-name">Price: ${subscriptionPrice}</p>
            <p class="submenu-all-subscriptions-name">Duration time: ${subscriptionDurationTime}</p>
            <button class="submenu-all-subscriptions-button" onclick="updateSubscription('${subscriptionName}')">Subscribe</button>
        </li>
    `;
});
findAllSubmenu.innerHTML += '</ul>';
findAllSubmenu.style.display = 'block';

}
function updateSubscription(subscriptionName) {
const jwtToken = getCookie('JWT_TOKEN');
if (!jwtToken) {
    console.error('JWT token not found');
    return;
}
if (!subscriptionName) {
    console.error('Subscription name is required');
    return;
}
const requestData = {
    newSubscription: {
        subscriptionName: subscriptionName
    }
};
fetch('/personal_office/update_subscription', {
    method: 'PUT',
    headers: {
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${jwtToken}`,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(requestData)
})
.then(response => {
    if (!response.ok) {
        return response.text().then(text => {
            throw new Error(text);
        });
    }
    return response.text();
})
.then(responseMessage => {
    displayMessage(responseMessage, 'success');
    showSubscriptionOnScreen();
    showSubscriptionEndTimeOnScreen();
})
.catch(error => {
    console.error('Failed to update subscription: ', error);
    displayMessage(error.message, 'error');
});

}
  

Disabling cord won’t help because CORS is enforced by all modern browsers, therefore u need to configure CORS on backend - see how to configure CORS here, if you want to understand the problem a bit better then I made this (shameless self plug) video explaining the topic for spring and angular

This is likely not CORS related, but it could be.  You'll need to pin down exactly which request and to where it's failing and open a question on that.

What else could be the problem? I only receive the TypeError: Failed to fetch error on the front end in cases of subscription changes (where a request is sent from the front end to a controller on port 8080, which then forwards the request to port 8081). When changing other data, where requests are sent from the front end to controllers on port 8080 and responses are returned to the front end, this error does not occur. I've also added some code in the description.

Did you try @CrossOrigin("*") on your Controller class?

If you do suspect CORS then the browser ought to be making an OPTIONS call before the POST.  Is it?

I found that the error is not due to CORS. I have included all the details, the screenshot, and the code in the description. If anyone can, please explain what to do next.

It's really hard to say anything without a Minimal Reproducible Example. If you provide one you might find the answer on the road.
I seems like backend doesn't provide a response, and so the backend code needs to be examined in order to determine why.
